# Adding a new column of values to SQL table (large dataset!)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm dealing with a dataset with 200 million rows of data. Here's a simplified form of the problem I'm facing.

My current SQL (SQLite to be precise) table looks like this

```
timestamp  foo
1          251
2          459
3          147
```

I want to add a new column `bar` with values 693, 589, 289 (in that order) to get

```
timestamp  foo  bar
1          251  693
2          459  589
3          147  289
```

Using `UPDATE table SET new_value WHERE cond` as you can imagine is terribly slow.

I am open any solution. Even those containing recreation of the database but of course if there's a magic one liner that does the job that would be good too!

Comment: I think update is as fast as you're going to get here.

Comment: Are your columns indexed? Did you set the foreign keys for them ex foo_id in table 1 is a foreign key for the id in the foo table?

Comment: @Ming - In what order do you want to apply those ordered values? in the order of increasing timestamp?

Comment: Create an index if possible and use 
"UPDATE /* + parallel(16)  */ table SET new_value WHERE cond" this will speed up the update to some extent.

Comment: @GurV also hunijkah You guys are right! increasing timestamps!

Comment: @bharathkumarch Though it would still be an O(n^2) operation due to the conditional in WHERE. With 200 million rows of data, each individual update takes over 5 seconds. Even if each node can do an update in 1 second or less and I'm running 16 nodes at once, it would still take > 100 days

Comment: 200 million rows of data, and you want 693, 589, 289 over and over again?

Comment: @jarlh No they are completely new values. They don't hold any relations with the rest of the dataset. FYI I'm working on tick data but the dataset that I got is all serialized.

Answer (score 0):

An insert into a big data table is normally not slow. I guess the "processing" of the condition takes so much time.

You can check if this is the case by trying a select statement with the same condition.

If the condition is slow you should performance optimize your table. Normally you should add index on each column which is compared against many data sets.

Comment: I am guessing that the index in my case would be the timestamp. It is an unique value for each row. You're right, the processing of the condition is killer. Esp when you have > 2e8 rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking bout a solution involving the creation of a new table.

Lets call my original table 'A' and I want to migrate it into table 'B' (which is a clone of A but with an extra column that I want to insert)

For each row in A, I just have to append the new column value and insert the newly created row into B.

It would take a while on the 100GB of data that I'm working on but possible.